# Media Foundation: WavSink spools audio faster than real time consumption rate - can spooling be constrained real-time?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, real-time, ms-media-foundation

As title, I've worked from Media Foundation WavSink example which decodes an audio stream to PCM & dumps to a file.

My application is to direct this stream to the FMOD audio engine instead, which consumers PCM audio at real-time rates - as heard.

WavSink spools decoded audio faster than its played resulting in an unnecessary build up of decoded audio in memory. I'd like to limit this so we don't decode too far ahead to avoid wasting memory & compute resources - to run efficiently.

I've tried various approaches but whatever I do causes the video stream to glitch.

Was wondering if anyone could provide some insight that'll allow decode gating without glitching video.

Associated support query on MSDN Forums: [Redirected audio streams faster than associated video resulting in unwanted large decoded buffer build up](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d76a874b-8e3a-4e8b-b1ad-47101bc7e19f/redirected-audio-streams-faster-than-associated-video-resulting-in-unwanted-large-decoded-buffer?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment)

Answer (score 0):

You enable Media Foundation media pipeline to send you new data into sink by queuing a `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` event, [such as](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/wavsink/wavsink/wavsink.cpp#L1697):

```
        // Kick things off by requesting two samples...
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = QueueEvent(MEStreamSinkRequestSample, GUID_NULL, hr, NULL);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = QueueEvent(MEStreamSinkRequestSample, GUID_NULL, hr, NULL);
        }
```

Just avoid doing it until you really need new data.

Comment: That's almost it, Roman, thanks .. way better than I had but its still not quite right.

When I pull audio in bursts this way you can see the effect in the video, it bursts too - not what I want. Perhaps I need to decouple clocks or something as audio tick is causing video to tick too, or something like that. 

Any further insight you can offer ?

Thanks though, that's almost the right approach, just needs a little refining.

Comment: `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` is how you control the flow of audio and prevent from overbuffering. You have the flexibility how to queue the events, it does not have to be exactly like in the code snippets I quoted with two at a time, you just need to know it's `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` and the rest is up to you. It should not interfere with video, maybe you have another separate problem there.

Comment: should not, but does. I can smooth it out by not bursting requests. then maybe another day play with clocks to see if its that. will do for now, cheers.